# React axios php mysql. Works on localhost but not live

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, axios

I have a React app with a mysql database connected with PHP and Axios, it works perfect on localhost but not on my live host. I can even post contact details from the deployed app do my localhost db, but not to the live db. No error messages, nothing just goes to the live db. Not even empty rows. Nothing.

Mysql on localhost is apache and on the live host nginx. Could it be something related to that? Anybody with an idea why this happen me?
http://hakvik.se/react/#/contact

Comment: It can literally be anything. You need to do some debugging to find out _where_ it fails. Have you checked the console? Checked the network tab in the browsers developer tools to debug the request/response? Checked the servers error log?

Comment: I just tried your form. A message comes up that it was saved, but the response from the server is the complete app (all HTML). I seems like it's just posting the data to the same URL `/react`

Comment: Tricky. I am close to give up. Have been sitting for days with this.
This is my axios request.     axios.post('http://hakvik.se/react/#/src/api/index.php/?/user',

Comment: The request is being made at `http://hakvik.se/react/` and not the actual API. I think that' s the issue.

Comment: .............................................Tried to remove my comment but they demanded at least 15 characters. I have at least learnt this today.